# Summing hours under a threshold using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on a staff rota app and want to sum only the hours below a threshold of 2250 minutes (37.5 hours). I am struggling to isolate these hours however and the reason being is as follows. Firstly I'm new to LINQ.

Secondly, there are two different pay types that can be entered into the app, so I have to sum both pay types using `.Sum()` which is fine. The problem I'm having is isolating only the summed hours below 37.5 hours

I am grouping the results and running something like

```cs
g.Sum(x => x.Start >= start && x.End <= End ? x.Type1 : 0) +
g.Sum(x => x.Start >= start && x.End <= End ? x.Type2 : 0) <= 2250 ? .....
// then count the hours below here.
```

Now I get that this example will return zero if the count exceeds 2250, but how do I create a subset of the values below 2250 only?

Comment: so you need a list of hours when sum is less than or equal to 2250? and it should be only linq solution?

Comment: Hey Roman, Thats correct. I need the list of hours broken down between type1 and type2 beneath the threshold

Comment: Given your description and example code, it looks to me that you are comparing the _pay types_ with the minutes threshold, rather than comparing _work time_ with the threshold. What exactly is `Type1` and `Type2`? Are they in fact the total minutes worked (associated with the different pay types)?

Comment: Both of the pay types are variations of a shift so you can work 8 hours of type1 then 8 hours of type2 if that makes sense.

Comment: I understand. My question was perhaps not clear. Without knowing the class you are working with, but seeing how you _describe_ the pay types, I interpreted `Type1` to be a property that represents a _pay type_. As an example, `Type1` could be a custom enum `PayType`, so that `Type1` could have the value `PayType.Hourly`, `PayType.Weekly` or `PayType.Monthly`. But considering how you are using `Type1` in your code example, it rather seems to be of a numeric type. If the latter is the case, I would suggest renaming the `Type*` properties to something like `MinutesWorkedForPayType*` for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Type1` is *minutes worked for pay type 1* and `Type2` is *minutes worked for pay type 2*, you could go about it as follows:

1. Filter the relevant items based on your `Start` and `End` conditions
2. For each item, calculate the total minutes worked (`Type1` + `Type2`)
3. Filter the total minutes by comparing them to the threshold
4. Summing total minutes items that are below the threshold

In Linq,

- filtering can be done using [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0)
- creating a new object for each item in the collection can be done using [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0)

Implementation:

```csharp
int threshold = 2250;

int filteredTotalMinutes = g
    .Where(x => x.Start >= start && x.End <= end)
    .Select(x => x.Type1 + x.Type2)
    .Where(minutesWorked => minutesWorked <= threshold)
    .Sum();
```

Another possible approach is to do all the filtering first, and then sum the total minutes worked:

```csharp
int filteredTotalMinutes = g
    .Where(x => x.Start >= start && x.End <= end)
    .Where(x => x.Type1 + x.Type2 <= threshold)
    .Sum(x => x.Type1 + x.Type2);
```

These implementations will only take into account the work time of the employees that have worked less than or equal to the threshold.

---

If you rather need to include work time for *all* employees, but *limit the maximum work time that is included in the calculation for each employee to the threshold* (i.e. **for each employee, use `sum = x.Type1 + x.Type2` if `sum` is less than or equal to the threshold; else, use the threshold**), you may utilize [`Math.Min()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=net-6.0) to get the lowest value of the total minutes worked (`x.Type1 + x.Type2`) and the threshold.

The implementation can now be simplified:

```csharp
int filteredTotalMinutes = g
    .Where(x => x.Start >= start && x.End <= end)
    .Sum(x => Math.Min(x.Type1 + x.Type2, threshold));
```

If `Type1` and/or `Type2` are nullable (e.g. `int?`), you need to ensure that `Math.Min()` actually has `int` values to work with. You will then need to provide a fallback for each nullable value.

This can be achieved by replacing `x.Type*` with `(x.Type* ?? 0)`, which reads:
*Take the value of `x.Type*` if `x.Type*` is not `null`; else, take `0`*.

If both `Type*` properties are nullable, the implementation hence becomes:

```csharp
int filteredTotalMinutes = g
    .Where(x => x.Start >= start && x.End <= end)
    .Sum(x => Math.Min((x.Type1 ?? 0) + (x.Type2 ?? 0), threshold));
```

---

If you cannot use `Math.Min()`, you could perhaps rather use a ternary operator to select the desired work time portion for each employee. I would then first calculate the total minutes worked for each employee, and then decide if the total minute amount or the threshold value should be used:

```csharp
int filteredTotalMinutes = g
    .Where(x => x.Start >= start && x.End <= end)
    .Select(x => (x.Type1 ?? 0) + (x.Type2 ?? 0))
    .Sum(minutesWorked => minutesWorked < threshold 
        ? minutesWorked 
        : threshold);
```

Comment: Hey Astrid thank you very much for the help. I have implemented your solution and it works really well but there is 1 caveat I found. lets say i have worked 2000 minutes, then work an 8 hour shift so 450 minutes. This calculation doesnt take into account the portion of 450 (so 250 minutes) which falls below the threshold of 2250. Im sure this is a simple fix, but my brains not functioning right now

Comment: @Rowandinho Glad to help you on the right track! If I understand the caveat you describe correctly, it should be solved by utilizing `x => Math.Min(x.Type1 + x.Type2, threshold)`. I'll update my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: @Rowandinho Answer is now updated with a simplified implementation, addressing (my interpretation of) your comment.

Comment: Hey Astrid, thank you for your help. I am using entity framework which i should have mentioned and the Math.Min isnt playing nicely. I am getting a cannot convert int? to byte warning so i tried to cast with  x => Math.Min((int)x.Type1 + x.Type2, threshold) and that gave errors too :(

Comment: I should have said im using entity framework, so i figure it doesnt like Math.Min()

Comment: @Rowandinho If `Type1` and `Type2` are nullable (i.e. `int?`), it may help to provide `0` as a fallback for a `null` value: `Math.Min((x.Type1 ?? 0) + (x.Type2 ?? 0), threshold)`

Comment: Hey Astrid, thank you for your help. I tried your solution but I think the issue lies with entity framework as its unable to convert Math.Min it appears

Comment: @Rowandinho You are welcome. Okay, I have added a final suggestion of using a ternary operator rather than `Math.Min()`. If that does not solve the issues, let's hope someone else comes along with a helpful answer. :)